# ASP.NET MVC 4 Loading lookup data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I was wondering how dropdownlists shoud be loaded ?  How people do that usually ? The data in my dropdown are quite disconnected from my Model so they should not come from the Model.

Should I use the new MVC web api services to return the required data  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) ,it describes basic way to use dropdown list in asp.net mvc and its quite simple also